# Router-outlet refreshing entire site

Tags: angular, angular8, router-outlet

First of all sorry for my bad english.

I´m currently working in an app built with Angular 8. For the routing we are using **Router-Outlet**

At first we made a mockup of the app using Angular material. And it worked just perfect in there

```
  <mat-sidenav-container autosize class="sidenav-container" fixedInViewport="true">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over">
      <mat-nav-list *ngIf="this.authService.userData!=null">
        <mat-list-item class ="sidenav-itemlist"> <a routerLink="/home"  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="sidenav.close()" >{{ "Home" | translate }}</a> </mat-list-item>            
        <mat-list-item class ="sidenav-itemlist"> <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" (click)="sidenav.close()">{{ "About" | translate }}</a> </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item> <a routerLink="/company" (click)="sidenav.close()">{{ "Menu.Companies" | translate }}</a> </mat-list-item>   
        <mat-list-item class ="sidenav-itemlist"> <a  routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="sidenav.close() " >{{ "Log out" | translate }}</a> </mat-list-item>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content >
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>

  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

After that we started with the actual app ( leaving aside Material). But after doing it, when changing the route all the site is reloaded and not only the commponent intended and i´m not sure why is it happening

```
  <div id="page">
    <header tabindex="0" *ngIf="this.authService.userData!=null">SOD Tool</header>
    <div id="nav-container" *ngIf="this.authService.userData!=null">
      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="button" tabindex="0">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-content" tabindex="0" >
        <ul>
          <li><a routerLink="/home"  routerLinkActive="active" (click)="sidenav.close()" >{{ "Home" | translate }}</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" (click)="sidenav.close()">{{ "About" | translate }}</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/company" (click)="sidenav.close()">{{ "Menu.Companies" | translate }}</a></li>
          <!-- <li><a href="#0">About</a></li> -->
          <li><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="sidenav.close() " >{{ "Log out" | translate }}</a></li>
          <!-- <li class="small"><a href="#0">Facebook</a><a href="#0">Instagram</a></li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>

  </div>
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You write that when changing the route, all the site is reloaded? What do you mean by that? Everything inside the router-outlet will be changed, but the menu should stay the same. If that's what happening, then that's correct according to how you have set this up.

Comment: What i whant is that only the router-outlet is refreshed when changing the route, and not all the site like the nav container. What is happening is that when i change de route everything is loaded again. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you try and reproduce this in a small stackblitz ? @Tigre1902